# Linear Lie group.

Tags: lie-groups

Suppose that G is a connected Lie group such that the center of G is trivial.

Question:

Is it true that G is isomorphic (as Lie group) to a closed subgroup of a Linear group GL(n,R) for some natural number n. Or maybe there is an evident counterexample ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3011849/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: @mrtaurho I was wondering if we can think about some abstract Lie group as Lie subgroup of GL(n,R) for some n. That is my motivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjoint representation of $G$ realizes it as a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ (in general, the kernel of the adjoint representation consists of elements of $G$ that commute with the connected component of $G$ that contains the identity).

Comment: Naive question: why  the image of G by the adjoint representation is closed in GL(g)?

Comment: @Ofra It's not such a naive question! In general the image of a Lie group by a representation is not necessarily closed. However, in this case it follows from the facts that (i) the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism from $\mathfrak{g}$ onto $G$, (ii) the exponential is compatible with the adjoint representation, and (iii) a subgroup that is closed in some neighborhood of the identity is closed.